# Datetime comparison in C#

Tags: datetime

I have the current UTC datetime as follows:

```
 public void GetUTCTime()
        {
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            string utc = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Console.WriteLine("Current UTC time is: " + utc);
        }
```

My another date is like,

```
String myDate = "2017-06-15 16:10:16";
```

Now i have to find out which datetime is latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DateTime.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx):

```cs
if (DateTime.Compare(time_1, time_2) > 0) // if time_1 is later than time_2
{
    // Your code here
}
```

---

### According to the linked MSDN documentation:

If the returned value is...

- Less than zero: time_1 is earlier than time_2
- Zero: time_1 is the same as time_2
- Greater than zero: time_1 is later than time_2

### Converting the string date back to DateTime:

Since you're using the date as a string, you have to convert it back to DateTime before comparing, like that:

```cs
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse(stringDate);
```